# Overlay plots with different scales

Tags: python, matplotlib

So far I have the following code:

```
colors = ('k','r','b')
ax = []
for i in range(3):
    ax.append(plt.axes())
    plt.plot(datamatrix[:,0],datamatrix[:,i],colors[i]+'o')
    ax[i].set(autoscale_on=True)
```

With the `autoscale_on=True` option for each axis, I thought each plot should have its own y-axis limits, but it appears they all share the same value (even if they share different axes). How do I set them to scale to show the range of each `datamatrix[:,i]` (just an explicit call to `.set_ylim()`?) And also, how can I create an offset y-axis for the third variable (`datamatrix[:,2]`) that might be required above? Thanks all.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

It sounds like what you're wanting is subplots... What you're doing now doesn't make much sense (Or I'm very confused by your code snippet, at any rate...).

Try something more like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3)

colors = ('k', 'r', 'b')
for ax, color in zip(axes, colors):
    data = np.random.random(1) * np.random.random(10)
    ax.plot(data, marker='o', linestyle='none', color=color)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit:**

If you don't want subplots, your code snippet makes a lot more sense.

You're trying to add three axes right on top of each other.  Matplotlib is recognizing that there's already a subplot in that exactly size and location on the figure, and so it's returning the *same* axes object each time.  In other words, if you look at your list `ax`, you'll see that they're all *the same object*.

If you *really* want to do that, you'll need to reset `fig._seen` to an empty dict each time you add an axes.  You probably don't really want to do that, however.

Instead of putting three independent plots over each other, have a look at using `twinx` instead.

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# To make things reproducible...
np.random.seed(1977)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Twin the x-axis twice to make independent y-axes.
axes = [ax, ax.twinx(), ax.twinx()]

# Make some space on the right side for the extra y-axis.
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

# Move the last y-axis spine over to the right by 20% of the width of the axes
axes[-1].spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.2))

# To make the border of the right-most axis visible, we need to turn the frame
# on. This hides the other plots, however, so we need to turn its fill off.
axes[-1].set_frame_on(True)
axes[-1].patch.set_visible(False)

# And finally we get to plot things...
colors = ('Green', 'Red', 'Blue')
for ax, color in zip(axes, colors):
    data = np.random.random(1) * np.random.random(10)
    ax.plot(data, marker='o', linestyle='none', color=color)
    ax.set_ylabel('%s Thing' % color, color=color)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=color)
axes[0].set_xlabel('X-axis')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks -- actually I do want a single panel with all the points, but each having a different y scale...

Comment: Hopefully the edits help.  I'm assuming you want the y-axes labeled with the actual ranges. If you don't (and basically just want the y-values to be meaningless), then you can do this much more simply.

Comment: Ah, `spines` is the attribute I wanted I think. But manually adjusting the spine seems like the way to go, even with a "floating" axis which is not necessarily connected with the data, so long as I ensure that the scales are manipulated correctly! Thanks.

Comment: This is actually quite beautiful. I have copied this and put it to use already. One thing though, `tick_parms` does not exist? I had to set `axes[-1].yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')`, but otherwise worked beautifully!

Comment: `tick_params` was added in matplotlib `1.0.0`. You should consider upgrading to a more recent version.  There's been quite a bit added in the last couple of years.  Glad to hear you figured out a workaround, though!

Comment: Yeah the red axis somehow did not appear in the figure? can you fix it?

Comment: Use `handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` to collect all labels and `axes[0].legend(allHandles,allLabels)` to print the complete legend

Comment: @JoeKington, do you know why id could happen that, applying your code to my case, there is plenty of blank room by side the plot?

Comment: @Py-ser - If your figure is wider than the default, the 25% (of the width) padding this example has is probably too much.  Try tweaking the `0.75` and `1.2`  (e.g. to something like `0.85` and `1.1`).

Comment: @Py-ser - Actually, I just realized that recent versions of matplotlib have changed how `twinx` works. You can no longer call `twinx` twice and get two separate axes.  I'll update the example.

Comment: @JoeKington, I solved, it was enough to add `fig.tight_layout()`

Comment: Is it possible to color the numbers on the red axis red, if no red dots are plotted? I can only get the ticks and the text label to change color.

Answer (score 10):

Bootstrapping *something fast* to chart multiple y-axes sharing an x-axis using [@joe-kington's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7734614/1085495) answer:
[image]

```
# d = Pandas Dataframe, 
# ys = [ [cols in the same y], [cols in the same y], [cols in the same y], .. ] 
def chart(d,ys):

    from itertools import cycle
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    axes = [ax]
    for y in ys[1:]:
        # Twin the x-axis twice to make independent y-axes.
        axes.append(ax.twinx())

    extra_ys =  len(axes[2:])

    # Make some space on the right side for the extra y-axes.
    if extra_ys>0:
        temp = 0.85
        if extra_ys<=2:
            temp = 0.75
        elif extra_ys<=4:
            temp = 0.6
        if extra_ys>5:
            print 'you are being ridiculous'
        fig.subplots_adjust(right=temp)
        right_additive = (0.98-temp)/float(extra_ys)
    # Move the last y-axis spine over to the right by x% of the width of the axes
    i = 1.
    for ax in axes[2:]:
        ax.spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.+right_additive*i))
        ax.set_frame_on(True)
        ax.patch.set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.OldScalarFormatter())
        i +=1.
    # To make the border of the right-most axis visible, we need to turn the frame
    # on. This hides the other plots, however, so we need to turn its fill off.

    cols = []
    lines = []
    line_styles = cycle(['-','-','-', '--', '-.', ':', '.', ',', 'o', 'v', '^', '<', '>',
               '1', '2', '3', '4', 's', 'p', '*', 'h', 'H', '+', 'x', 'D', 'd', '|', '_'])
    colors = cycle(matplotlib.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'])
    for ax,y in zip(axes,ys):
        ls=line_styles.next()
        if len(y)==1:
            col = y[0]
            cols.append(col)
            color = colors.next()
            lines.append(ax.plot(d[col],linestyle =ls,label = col,color=color))
            ax.set_ylabel(col,color=color)
            #ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=color)
            ax.spines['right'].set_color(color)
        else:
            for col in y:
                color = colors.next()
                lines.append(ax.plot(d[col],linestyle =ls,label = col,color=color))
                cols.append(col)
            ax.set_ylabel(', '.join(y))
            #ax.tick_params(axis='y')
    axes[0].set_xlabel(d.index.name)
    lns = lines[0]
    for l in lines[1:]:
        lns +=l
    labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
    axes[0].legend(lns, labs, loc=0)

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Joe Kington's answer I could come up with a solution for my requirement that all additional y-axis are on the left hand side of the graph.

I still would like to know how to do it correct, because it's just a work around:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# To make things reproducible...
np.random.seed(1977)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Twin the x-axis twice to make independent y-axes.
axes = [ax, ax.twinx(), ax.twinx()]

# Make some space on the right side for the extra y-axis.
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

# Move the last y-axis spine over to the right by 20% of the width of the axes
axes[1].spines['right'].set_position(('axes', -0.25))
axes[2].spines['right'].set_position(('axes', -0.5))

# To make the border of the right-most axis visible, we need to turn the frame
# on. This hides the other plots, however, so we need to turn its fill off.
axes[-1].set_frame_on(True)
axes[-1].patch.set_visible(False)

# And finally we get to plot things...
colors = ('Green', 'Red', 'Blue')
intAxNo = 0
for ax, color in zip(axes, colors):
    intAxNo += 1
    data = np.random.random(1) * np.random.random(10)
    ax.plot(data, marker='o', linestyle='none', color=color)
    if (intAxNo > 1):
        if (intAxNo == 2):
            ax.set_ylabel('%s Thing' % color, color=color, labelpad = -40 )
        elif (intAxNo == 3):
            ax.set_ylabel('%s Thing' % color, color=color, labelpad = -45 )
        ax.get_yaxis().set_tick_params(direction='out')
    else:
        ax.set_ylabel('%s Thing' % color, color=color, labelpad = +0 )

    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors=color)
axes[0].set_xlabel('X-axis')


plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`twinx`. Short example:

```
fig1 = matplotlib.figure.Figure()  # Make a figure
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot()           # Add the primary axis
ax1.plot([100, 300, 200])          # Plot something
ax2 = ax1.twinx()                  # Add the secondary axis
ax2.plot([5000, 2000, 6000])       # Plot something with a different scale
display( fig1 )                    # Display it (Jupyter only)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've used this code and it successfully generated two Y-axes (primary & secondary) with desired scales reading data from Excel file:

```
X = df[['x-axis variable']]
Y1=df[['1st Y-Variable']]
Y2=df[['2nd Y-Variable']]
Y3=df[['3rd Y-Variable']]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(X, Y1, 'g', label='Curve.1 name') #plotting on primary Y-axis
ax1.plot(X, Y2, 'm', label='Curve.2 name') #plotting on primary Y-axis

ax2.plot(X, wob, 'b', label='Curve.3 name') #plotting on **second** Y-axis

ax1.set_ylim(0, 350) #Define limit/scale for primary Y-axis
ax2.set_ylim(1000, 1300) #Define limit/scale for secondary Y-axis

plt.show()
```