# Plot with many y-axis in different scales: how to tight figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I am following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733693/matplotlib-overlay-plots-with-different-scales) to produce a plot in which report different data sets whose x-axis is the same, but y-axis has different scales.
I can reproduce my plot, similar to this:

[image]

With some code:

```
# Twin the x-axis twice to make independent y-axes.
axes = [ax, ax.twinx(), ax.twinx()]

# Make some space on the right side for the extra y-axis.
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

# Move the last y-axis spine over to the right by 20% of the width of the axes
axes[-1].spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.2))

# To make the border of the right-most axis visible, we need to turn the frame
# on. This hides the other plots, however, so we need to turn its fill off.
axes[-1].set_frame_on(True)
axes[-1].patch.set_visible(False)
```

But it happens that, by side the figure, there is plenty of empty room, so that the figure is "squeezed" in 3/4 of the sheet, instead of being spread over the whole page.

Why does this happen? And what could be a possible way to avoid it?

Comment: works fine for me under python 2.7.6 and matplotlib 1.3.0, no visible "sqeeze" : https://i.imgur.com/ASrVKM6.png

Comment: @Louis, yes this is only part of the code, probably something else I add is bringing the squeezing, for example I add an upper x-axis too to the plot.

Comment: I just copy-pasted the code from your link "this discussion". Does this original code works for you ? What matplotlib are you using ? Did you modify the code ? If yes, please post it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would get this:

[image]

You may want to call `fig.tight_layout()` before calling `plt.show()`.

[image]

You also want to fiddle with the axis offset (`1.13` instead of `1.2`):

```
axes[-1].spines['right'].set_position(('axes', 1.13))
```